# FreeRTOS: Run other tasks (with lower priority) while delay

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, freertos, arduino-esp32

I want to run multiple tasks on the same core of my ESP32 via FreeRTOS. I'm using the Arduino IDE. As I understood, the task with lower priority is only run, when the task with higher priority is finished. But I want that if the high priority task delays itself, the low priority task is run until the delay is over. Then the high priority task should be continued.

I googled a bit and asked ChatGPT, but every website said another thing:

- Use `vTaskDelay()` or `vTaskDelayUntil()` (Sources which say to use it: [Arduino Forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/delay-a-freertos-esp32-8266-task-with-resume-using-semaphore/638213/3), ChatGPT; Source which say to not use it: [Arduino Forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/freertos-task-priority/908884/10)
- Use `semaphores` (Sources which say to use it: [Arduino Forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/delay-a-freertos-esp32-8266-task-with-resume-using-semaphore/638213), ChatGPT; Source which say to not use it: [Arduino Forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/delay-a-freertos-esp32-8266-task-with-resume-using-semaphore/638213/3)
- Use `vTaskSuspend()` and `vTaskResume()` (Source which say to use it: ChatGPT; Source which say to not use it: me)

I've tried nothing of that.
What is the best and easiest way to do it?

Comment: If a higher prio task waits for a delay to expire or blocks on something like a semaphore the lower prio task will run. Don’t use suspend/resume. Those functions are somewhat special. See https://www.freertos.org/implementation/a00005.html for details

Comment: @HS2 If I understood you correctly, I can run `delay()` and while the delay it runs the other tasks!? That would be very easy. I'll try that out. Many Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but use the FreeRTOS delay functions like vTaskDelay.

Comment: Yes, `vTaskDelay()` is a non-blocking delay, so your lower priority function should be able to run while the higher priority function is in delay. But that can only happen if the delay is long enough. If it is somewhere around twice the amount of a single tick, then it'll probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vTaskDelay` is the canonical way to delay task operation giving room for other tasks to run. Note that there is also `taskYIELD()`, which – for a short moment in time – transfers control to the scheduler to do its thing.